# Change the page when pressing a submit button in PHP

Tags: php, html

When I press the submit button "login" I want my page to go to "frontPage.php", but it goes instead to "login.php" even though I have specified

```
header("location: frontPage.php");
```

in my login.php.

login.php

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        if (empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
            echo "Please fill all fields";
        } else {
            $usernameinput = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $passwordinput = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";
            $stmt  = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                'username' => $usernameinput
            ));
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            
            if ($count > 0) {
                
                while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    
                    if (password_verify($passwordinput, $result["password"])) {
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $usernameinput;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                header("location: frontPage.php");
            } else {
                header("location: index.php");
            }
        }
    }
```

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" class="form" method="POST" action="login.php">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <button id="login">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `input`s have no `name` so they won't be accessible through PHP.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the attribute name of all inputs
try this

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" class="form" method="POST" action="login.php">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <button id="login" type="submit" name="login">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name attribute on the submit button. It should have an attribute of name=“login”.

All of your inputs are also missing the name attribute. Copy what you have for id attributes for the missing name attributes.

Comment: Here’s a good example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp

Comment: Answers have an "edit" button...you don't need to supplement the contents with comments :-)